# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined sails.io.js

Tags: javascript, socket.io, sails.js

I added socket.io-client.js to my front end application. Because backend is driven by sails.js I added a socket.io wrapper provided by sails:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/master/sails.io.js

When I refresh site I get an error in this line:

```
Socket.prototype.get = function(url, data, cb)
```

Console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
>   sails.io.js:311 SailsIOClient sails.io.js:311 (anonymous function)
>   sails.io.js:724 (anonymous function) sails.io.js:726

Is this some bug in the sails.io.js script? I am not using the script right now, just included it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of `sails.io.js` in that repo is under active development.  To safely implement `socket.io` in your Sails project, you can use the `sails.io.js` that is provided with new Sails projects created by the `sails new` command.

That having been said, the issue here is that you need to [include the *dist* version](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js/blob/master/dist/sails.io.js) of the repo's `sails.io.js` file, which includes the code for the `socket.io` client inline.  So don't include a separate copy of `socket.io.js` in your project if you go that route.  The new `sails.io.js` has a few key benefits:

1. Automatically connects to socket server
2. Provides a `response` argument to request callbacks with the response status, headers, etc.
3. Sails will automatically detect the new version of `sails.io.js` and respond accordingly

Again, it's under development so read the doc page carefully and use at your own risk!

Comment: The issue was, that sails.io.js does not work with the recent 1.0.0-pre version of socket.io-client.js

Answer (score 0):

I managed to have it working using the version 0.9.17 of socket.io-client